# Inverse CDF method to simulate a random sample

Tags: r, function, random, inverse, cdf

I have a problem where I have written this piece of code, however I think there might be an issue with it.

This is the question:
Write an R function called pr1 that simulates a random sample of size n from the distribution with the CDF which is given as..

```
F_X(x) = 0 for x<=10
     (x-10)^3/1000 for 10<x<20
    1 for x=>20
```

x = 10 ( 1 + u^(1/3)) #I have used the inverse CDF method here and I now want to simulate a random sample of size n from the distribution.

Here is my code:

```
 pr1 = function(n)

 { u = runif(n,0,1)
   x = 10 * ( 1 + u^(1/3))
   x }

 pr1(5)
```

#This was just to check an example with n=5

My question is, since the CDF is 10< x <20, will this affect my code in any way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you confusing the range of `X` with the sample size?  The former is restricted to the range (10, 20), the latter can be any positive integer.

You can do a sanity check on your inversion by considering U = 0, which should (and does) yield the minimum of the range of `X`, and U = 1, which should and does yield the maximum value of the range.  There is no need to range restrict your inversion, the restriction is built into the use of U(0,1)'s on the input side, combined with the fact that CDFs are monotonically non-decreasing.  Thus no value of U such that 0 < U < 1 can yield an outcome outside the range 10 < X < 20.

Comment: So does this mean the CDF is restricted, however x = 10 ( 1 + u^(1/3)) can be any positive integer? Does this mean my code is correct and I don't need to change it?

Comment: `X = 10 (1 + U^(1/3))` can ***not*** be any positive integer.  Since U ~ Uniform(0,1), `X` is restricted to be a decimal value between 10 and 20, exactly as it should be.  That's what the "sanity check" testing is about, to make sure the smallest and largest U produce the smallest and largest X, respectively.  (You can get the median of `X` by plugging in U = 0.5, as well.)

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to simulate a piece-wise function, your R function should contain some flow controls like `if`.

Here's a start:

```
pr1 = function(n, drawing_range){

    x <- sample(drawing_range, size = n) # random drawing of x

    if (x <= 10)  
         output <- 0
    else if ( 10 < x < 20 )
         output <- (x-10)^3/1000 
    else
         output <- 1

    output
}
```

`n` is the number of draws. `drawing_range` is the population from which you draw; for example it can be from [-999, 999] in which case you input `-999:999`.

Comment: This is evaluating the CDF, not generating `X`s using the inverse.  There is no need to range check `X`s with inversion.